# Range of values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, dataset

i need to show some parameters of my dataset, last one is range, but i couldn't find any useful info how to code this. If i understand right it is

```
range = max - min
```

This is my pandas function in jupiter notebook:

```
data.groupby("DPI").agg({"SUM_ALL" :["count",pd.Series.mode,"mean","median","min","max"]})
```

[my outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCPuh.png)

how to add one more column with `range` value?

Comment: You can use `numpy.ptp()` readily.   See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try defining a custom range function, such as:

```
def calc_range(x):
    return np.max(x) - np.min(x)
```

and then passing it as a function in agg:

```
data.groupby("DPI").agg({"SUM_ALL" :["count",pd.Series.mode,"mean","median","min","max", calc_range]})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`numpy.ptp()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) function directly for better clarity and efficiency:

[`numpy.ptp()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) is doing exactly what you want:

> Range of values (maximum - minimum) along an axis.
>
> The name of the function comes from the acronym for ‘peak to peak’.

So, plugging in to your code, we can use:

```
import numpy as np

data.groupby("DPI").agg({"SUM_ALL" :["count",pd.Series.mode,"mean","median","min","max", np.ptp]})
```